# WPF ListView - How to copy individual cells

Tags: wpf, listview, clipboard

I have code where I can take a look at the SelectedItem and then output ToString() to get the record into the clipboard.

How can I detect what cell the user is right clicking on in order to copy just that cell in the SelectedItem?

For example, if I have Borrower Information and the user right-clicks on last name, I would like to give the ability to just copy last name to clipboard.

Thank you!

UPDATE:

Here is the code that I used as suggested by Josh, it worked great:

```
  private void BorrowerInfoCopyClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BorrowerViewModel vm = this.DataContext as BorrowerViewModel;
            if (vm != null)
            {
                Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, vm.CurrentTextBlockText);
            }
        }

        private void AddressCopyClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BorrowerViewModel vm = this.DataContext as BorrowerViewModel;
            if (vm != null)
            {
                Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, vm.CurrentTextBlockText);
            }
        }

        private void lstViews_PreviewMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            BorrowerViewModel vm = this.DataContext as BorrowerViewModel;
            if (vm != null)
            {
                if (e.OriginalSource is TextBlock)
                {
                    TextBlock txtBlock = e.OriginalSource as TextBlock;
                    vm.CurrentTextBlockText = txtBlock.Text;
                }
```

}
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this by handling the PreviewMouseRightButtonDown event on the ListView and checking if e.OriginalSource is a TextBlock. If so, copy the txtBlk.Text to the clipboard. This code could either be in the code-behind of the View that contains the ListView, or as a behavior you attach to the ListView. If you need to use a context menu to perform the Copy operation, have a TextBlock field that you use to store a reference to the TextBlock, and in your method that responds to a MenuItem's click (or Command execution) reference the TextBlock there instead.

Comment: Josh, Thank you for your prompt answer. That did the trick. I am using a context menu for "Copy". Here is my code. Thanks again!